# How to migrate manifest version 2 to v3 for chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I can't get my head around how to upgrade my chrome extension manifest v2 to v3

I checked https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/migrating_to_manifest_v3 but it doesn't talk about the manifest.json

any idea what it needs to be changed in my manifest here :-

```
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "short_name": "Ex",
    "author": "User",
    "description": "cool chrome ex",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "ex",
        "default_icon": "img/logo.png"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html",
        "open_in_tab": true
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "background",
        "storage"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "128": "img/logo128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "matches": [
                "https://conferfly.com/*",
                "https://meet.google.com/*",
                "https://teams.microsoft.com/*",
                "https://*.zoom.us/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "js/main.js",
                "js/injected.js"
            ],
            "css": [
                "css/main.css"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/options.js",
        "js/main.js",
        "js/injected.js"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

thank you in advance

---

This is for [conferfly](https://conferfly.com) extension

Comment: It says "Replace background.page or background.scripts with background.service_worker in manifest.json. Note that the service_worker field takes a string, not an array of strings." And of course change 2 to 3 in manifest_version.

Answer (score 126):

Here is an example of how to migrate `manifest.json` from v2 to v3.

First thing is to change the `manifest_version` key from `2` to `3`

```
//Manifest v2
"manifest_version": 2

//Manifest v3
"manifest_version": 3
```

Replace `pageAction` and `browserAction` with `action` in js files.

Replace `browser_action` and `page_action` keys with `action`:

```
//Manifest v2
"browser_action": {...}
"page_action": {...}

//Manifest v3
"action": {...}
```

Background pages and background scripts are deprecated into manifest v3. They are replaced from service workers. This means that the `background` section of the manifest file needs to be modified in this way

```
//Manifest v2
"background": {
 "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
}

//Manifest v3
"background": {
 "service_worker": "js/background.js"
}
```

To declare the packed resources that needs to be accessed from the web, the `web_accessible_resources` needs to be changed in this way

```
//Manifest v2
"web_accessible_resources": [
        "js/options.js",
        "js/main.js",
        "js/injected.js"
]

//Manifest v3
"web_accessible_resources": [{
 "resources": ["js/options.js","js/main.js","js/injected.js"],
 "matches": [],
 "extension_ids": []
}]
```

Content security policy in v3 is an object

```
//Manifest v2
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'" 

//Manifest v3
"content_security_policy": {
 "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
 "sandbox": "..."
}
```

To have more information about  you can check [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/) or [this one](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: Great answer! Just for reference, [Manifest v3 no longer supports 'unsafe-eval' in CSP for `extension_pages`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#:~:text=MV3%20disallows%20certain%20CSP%20modifications).

Comment: Wow man. You saved my life. To let anybody else know. Even though the `matches` and `extension_ids` are not yet used, they MUST be present.

Comment: also background.js file must be moved to the root folder so need to change "js/background.js" to "background.js"

Comment: Wow these migration guides are terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a very good explained guide: https://blog.shahednasser.com/chrome-extension-tutorial-migrating-to-manifest-v3-from-v2/