# Why am I getting "Failed to load extension. Invalid value for 'content_security_policy'"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am trying to create a chrome extension. My manifest file is

```
{
    "name": "Alert-Beep",
    "action": {},
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Beeps if alert() is called",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*.com/*"],
        "js": ["alert-beep.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
    ]
}
```

Loading the extension fails with the message

```
Failed to load extension
File
~\alert-beep
Error
Invalid value for 'content_security_policy'.
Could not load manifest.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#fcontent-security-policy): CSP is now a dictionary object.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this answer to be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308160/how-to-migrate-manifest-version-2-to-v3-for-chrome-extension

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An additional example that helped me:

**manifest v3**

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://music.yandex.ru/;"
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the docs talking about this?

Answer (score 6):

I've looked into CSP for chrome extensions (go [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) to learn more for manifest v3).

**Use**

```
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since manifest is now updated to V3, content_security_policy is a dictionary. in this case, you should change this line

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
```

to this

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "script-src": "self",
    "object-src": "self"
 }
```

read more here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy