# How to set img src to png file in project using JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and hoping to customize it by adding icons.

The extension is using vanilla JS, so we create our HTML elements using js.
I have been able to use imported .png icons in the HTML popup, but when I am in my js file and try to set the img src to the correct path of the .png I get an error that looks like chrome is adding my path to the end of the current URL. Obviously that URL doesn't exist, so I error out and never see the icon.

[Why can't I do <img src="C:/localfile.jpg">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090712/why-cant-i-do-img-src-c-localfile-jpg)
sounds similar to what I am trying to do, but I don't want the image saved on my drive anywhere, I want it from within the project. Adding `file://` or `e://` before the path didn't work anyway.
I do see a `Not allowed to load local resource:` error when I prepend with `file://` so maybe it really is a security issue?

Is it simply going to be a security concern to add an icon to my buttons? anyone know of a  work around? Maybe someone knows of an online library where I could grab a url of an icon similar to https://fontawesome.com/icons/exclamation-circle?style=solid (I haven't been able to create an element from that html button either)

Ideally, I would be able to use the icon png my product team provided.
I am starting general just trying to get the icon to show up on the page where I have other elements appended. Here is what I have done to add the icon so far:

JS file:

```
const allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
const buttonContainerNode = allDivs[0].firstChild

let alertIcon = document.createElement("img");
alertIcon.src = "file:///images/alert_small.png"
buttonContainerNode.appendChild(alertIcon);
```

when visiting this product page https://www.target.com/p/general-mills-cheerios-honey-nut-breakfast-cereal-19-5oz/-/A-14765766#lnk=sametab on target.com the above code results in this 404 error:
GET https://www.target.com/images/alert_small.png 404

EDIT:
Part of my problem has been that I didn't add the icon resource to my manifest.json

I tried adding a top level icon section like this https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/icons/
Looks like that didn't change my error, nor did trying the suggested web_accessible_resources

Current manifest.json:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A nutritional claims checker ",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": ["./content.css"],
      "matches": ["*://www.target.com/*"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["/images/small_alert.png"],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "webNavigation", "*://www.target.com/*"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Demo extension",
    "default_icon": "/images/logoE4572E.png",
    "default_badge": "extension"
  }
}
```

I have been trying setting the src to `"/images/alert_small.png"` (GET https://www.target.com/images/outline_info_black_24dp.png 404)
and to `"file:///images/alert_small.png"` (Not allowed to load local resource: file:///images/small_alert.png)

Comment: See examples of using `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: Got it! I didn't find helpful chrome docs, but the mozilla docs were helpful!
Difference being I ran `chrome.runtime.getURL("image.png")` instead of `browser.runtime...` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources
Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the help of wOOxxOm I got the icon to show up.
Changes in my manifest.json file were pretty straight forward, helped out by the answer of this question [How to migrate manifest version 2 to v3 for chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63308160/how-to-migrate-manifest-version-2-to-v3-for-chrome-extension)

```
"manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A nutritional claims checker ",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": ["./content.css"],
      "matches": ["*://www.target.com/*"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["*.png"],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "webNavigation", "*://www.target.com/*"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Demo extension",
    "default_icon": "/images/logoE4572E.png",
    "default_badge": "extension"
  }
}
```

in my js file I created the icon element and assigned the source like this:

```
    const alertIcon = document.createElement("img");
    const source = chrome.runtime.getURL("images/small_alert.png");
    alertIcon.src = source;
    iconDiv.appendChild(alertIcon);
```

mozilla docs were helpful for this part (but obviously for a chrome extension use `chrome.runtime...` instead of `browser.runtime...`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources